# Filtering Excel file in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have been working for 2 days on this, i have excel file contain types and numbers, and I need to get all numbers for specific type,

[image]

I tried this but didn't work with me:

```
public void ReadExcel(string SelectedType)
{
    string excelName = "";            
    OpenFileDialog dialogRead = new OpenFileDialog();
    dialogRead.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    dialogRead.ShowDialog();
    excelName = dialogRead.FileName;
    Application excelApp = new Application();
    Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelName);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook
        .Sheets["INVENTORY "];
    FilterByCellValue(worksheet, "V", SelectedType);
    string newFilePath = "FilteredExcelFile.xlsx";
    workbook.SaveAs(newFilePath);
    excelApp.Quit();
}
static void FilterByCellValue(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet, string column, string cellValue)
{
    Range dataRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
    Range filterColumn = (Range)dataRange.Columns[column];

    filterColumn.AutoFilter(1, cellValue, XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Type.Missing, true);
}
```

I was expecting to get all the numbers of the choosing type but i get this exception `_AutoFilter method of Range class failed`.

Comment: Is it the the exact and complete error message? On which exact line does it correspond?

Comment: i only get the exception after the FilterByCellValue methods run inside the ReadExcel method.

Comment: Just a side note - you nee to also keep track of every COM object you create and explicitly release the COM object with a call to `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`. And that's every reference - even ones you dot over. You have at least one workbook, a worksheet, and two ranges you need to release.

Comment: Check the answer that I posted. that will set you on the right path.

Comment: BTW your screenshot doesn't match with what you want? You are filtering Col V but showing results from Col A and B?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that the screenshot was just a dummy example to show you what i need not the actual data i work on to respect my client privacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the range correctly. Here is an example that I created for you.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Hardcoded Excel filename. Change as applicbale
           string excelName = "C:\\Temp\\Book1.xlsx";

           Excel.Application excelApp;
           Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
           Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            
           excelApp = new Excel.Application{Visible = true};
           xlWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelName);

           // Change the name of the sheet here
           xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets["Sheet1"];

           // I have hardcoded the filter value. change as applicable
           string SelectedType = "4";

            FilterByCellValue(xlWorkSheet, "V", SelectedType);
        }

        static void FilterByCellValue(Excel.Worksheet worksheet, string column, string cellValue)
        {
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            Excel.Range dataRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
            
            // Get the column number where you want to filter
            int ColNumber = worksheet.Range[column + 1].Column;

            // Filter the data range
            dataRange.AutoFilter2(ColNumber, cellValue, Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, misValue, true);
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]